can you have Form actions in server components?

Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.   <form onSubmit={function} children=...>                  ^^^^^^^^^^ If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.

I'm trying to use a server action and a form in one component server component, but I keep getting errors. Is it possible to keep the form in the server component, or do I have to move the form to its own client component?
what I want: when a user clicks a button

takes some data from the server component (ie slug and publicId)

passes that data into a server action

revalidate the current path


'use server'
import { insertPrivateAccount} from "@/actions/companyActions";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export default async function CompanyProfile({ params }: {params: { slug: string }}) {

    const company = await getPublicAccount(slug);
    const publicId = await company.id;

    const addToPrivateCompany = () => {
        insertPrivateAccount(publicId, slug);
        revalidatePath(`/dashboard/accounts/${slug}`);
    };
  
    return (
        <form onSubmit={addToPrivateCompany}>
            <button>Add Account to Targets</button>
        </form>
    )
}

I have tried to add 'use server' inside the server actions that is on the current page

Due to the very nature of client and server components, you must create a new component.
Server components are designed to be static and render on the server, however all button clicks and form submissions require scripts on the client side. This means to handle button submissions, you have to create code on the client via a client component. A full guide is published here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns.
One more thing to note is that 'use server', is only meant for server actions, rather than components, so while you should use 'use server' in @/actions/companyActions, there is no need to have it in the current file

Forms are supposed to be on the client side make a separate component of its own.
Instead of onSubmit use action and pass the server action into it and drill the payload, make a server triggered request from server action to the next api:
This code may not be syntaxwise correct just for the sake of understanding
'use server'
    
export default async function loginAction(payload) {
  // handle the payload and make a request
}

const handleform = (payload) => {
  loginAction(payload);
};

<form action={handleForm}>
  <input />
  <input />
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

